# Pythonic way of doing composition aliases

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic and correct way of doing composition aliases?

Here's a hypothetical scenario:

```py
class House:
    def cleanup(self, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=False):
        # do something

class Person:
    def __init__(self, house): 
        self.house = house
        # aliases house.cleanup
        # 1.
        self.cleanup_house = self.house.cleanup

    # 2.
    def cleanup_house(self, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=False):
        return self.house.cleanup(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1)
```

AFAIK with #1 my tested editors understand these just as fine as #2 - auto completion, doc strings etc.

Are there any down-sides to #1 approach? Which way is more correct from python's point of view?

To expand on method #1 unsettable and type hinted variant would be immune to all of the issues pointed out in the comments:

```
class House:

    def cleanup(self, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=False):
        """clean house is nice to live in!"""
        pass


class Person:
    def __init__(self, house: House):
        self._house = house
        # aliases
        self.cleanup_house = self.house.cleanup

    @property
    def house(self):
        return self._house
```

Comment: What if a person gets a new house?

Comment: Not in this economy! Joking aside I guess making house attribute unsettable and adding a setter would do it. The question now is which is easier to maintain - this or rewriting signatures of many methods?

Comment: #2 is consistent with what one would intuitively expect `Person.cleanup_house` to do.  It gets the house associated with that person, and cleans it up.  #1 will cleanup some house, and at some point in time (initialization), that house was the correct one.  It doesn't deal well with the Person changing houses, or if a Person has no house

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the first method:

1. The alias won't update when the attribute it refers to changes unless you jump through extra hoops. You could, for example, make `house` a `property` with a setter, but that is non-trivial work for something that shouldn't require it. See the end of this answer for a sample implementation.
2. `cleanup_house` will not be inheritable. A function object defined in a class is a non-data descriptor that can be inherited and overridden, as well as be bound to an instance. An instance attribute like in the first approach is not present in the class at all. The fact that it is a bound method is incidental. A child class will not be able to access `super().cleanup_house`, for a concrete example.
3. `person.cleanup_house.__name__ != 'cleanup_house'`. This is not something you check often, but when you do, you would expect the function name to be `cleanup`.

The good news is that you don't have to repeat signatures multiple times to use approach #2. Python offers the very convenient splat (`*`)/splatty-splat (`**`) notation for delegating all argument checking to the method being wrapped:

```
def cleanup_house(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.house.cleanup(*args, **kwargs)
```

And that's it. All regular and default arguments are passed through as-is.

This is the reason that #2 is by far the more pythonic approach. I have no idea how it will interact with editors that support type hints unless you copy the method signature.

One thing that may be a problem is that `cleanup_house.__doc__` is not the same as `house.cleanup.__doc__`. This could potentially merit a conversion of `house` to a `property`, whose setter assigns `cleanup_house.__doc__`.

---

To address issue 1. (but not 2. or 3.), you can implement `house` as a property with a setter. The idea is to update the aliases whenever the `house` attribute changes. This is not a good idea in general, but here is an alternative implementation to what you have in the question that will likely work a bit better:

```
class House:
    def cleanup(self, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=False):
        """clean house is nice to live in!"""
        pass


class Person:
    def __init__(self, house: House):
        self.house = house  # use the property here

    @property
    def house(self):
        return self._house

    @house.setter
    def house(self, value):
        self._house = house
        self.cleanup_house = self._house.cleanup
```

Comment: However `*args, **kwargs` break auto completion features and in general are awkward to work with. You also need to define docstrings twice for `house.cleanup` and `person.cleanup_house` or hack them in somehow. So with this approach you need to constantly maintain the signatures and docstrings manually which can be a lot of work in big programs.

Comment: @Granitosaurus. I'm not sure how `*args` and `**kwargs` are awkward. They are literally there so you don't have to maintain signatures. `__doc__` can be maintained by direct assignment.

Comment: well args and kwargs obfuscate the signature and editors don't know what are the expected values - kinda awkward to work with. Though it seems this issue can be _kinda_ solved by adding `functool.wraps(<parent_func>)` decorator, though that introduces a lot of inconsistencies as well.

Comment: I really prefer your suggested approach with setters! I've just tested it and it's fully functional with expected editor functions (auto complete, signatures and docs, at least on PyCharm)!

Comment: @Granitosaurus. As long as you're aware of the functional issues, the approach you select is entirely for you to decide.

Comment: Talking about editor/IDE functions kind of twists the problem. I don't think you'll end up with better quality code thinking that way. Using *args and **kwargs is often used  and is pretty clear to Python developers. I've seen it a lot for example in django code. As you asked for the most pythonic, I think it has to be that way.

Comment: @rolf82 I disagree with you - I think that's a very important issue. API readability is important, be it computer or a person. In fact Django and other projects are often criticized for args/kwargs abuse!

Comment: @Granitosaurus. Criticized by who?

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add one more approach here, which if you want `house` to be public and settable (I would generally treat such a thing as immutable), you can make `cleanup_house` the property, like so:

```
class House:
    def cleanup(self, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=False):
        """clean house is nice to live in!"""
        print('cleaning house')


class Person:
    def __init__(self, house: House):
        self.house = house

    @property
    def cleanup_house(self):
        return self.house.cleanup
```

At least in an Ipython REPL, the code-completion and docstring seems to be working as you'd hope. Note sure how it would interact with type annotations...

EDIT: so, mypy 0.740 at least cannot infer the type signature of `person.cleanup_house`, so that's not great, although, it's not surprising:

```
(py38) Juans-MBP:workspace juan$ cat test_mypy.py
class House:
    def cleanup(self, arg1:int, arg2:bool):
        """clean house is nice to live in!"""
        print('cleaning house')


class Person:
    house: House
    def __init__(self, house: House):
        self.house = house  # use the property here

    @property
    def cleanup_house(self):
        return self.house.cleanup

person = Person(House())
person.cleanup_house(1, True)
person.cleanup_house('Foo', 'Bar')
reveal_type(person.cleanup_house)
reveal_type(person.house.cleanup)
(py38) Juans-MBP:workspace juan$ mypy test_mypy.py
test_mypy.py:19: note: Revealed type is 'Any'
test_mypy.py:20: note: Revealed type is 'def (arg1: builtins.int, arg2: builtins.bool) -> Any'
```

I would still just go with #2.

Comment: This beats my idea of writing a non-data descriptor to act like a wrapper function but also forward the annotations and signature of the target.